# Pie Chart with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart

I want to have a JavaScript pie chart, I already have one with PlotKit, but it's a too large library and my bandwidth is low. I want a good and low weighted one in JavaScript (or better, in jQuery).

Comment: I've used the Filament Group stuff and it's been great: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/charting/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google supplies a webservice returning charts.   More info here :

http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/chart/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links to sites with JQuery charting plug-ins:

http://www.jscharts.com/

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

and THIS SO thread, which is asking essentially the same question:

[Pie chart with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery)

EDIT: Added some other options

I recently used Flot to do some bar charts
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

and we're using Raphael for some pie charts and other stuff
http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: It's not "essentially the same question"

Answer (score 2):

i used this http://www.jqplot.com/index.php library on one of my projects. powerful and easy to use!
And here is an example with pie charts: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pieTests.php

Answer (score 2):

> There is a growing number of Open
>   Source and commercial solutions for
>   pure JavaScript charting that do not
>   require Flash. In this response I will
>   only present Open Source options.
>
> There are 2 main classes of JavaScript
>   solutions for graphics that do not
>   require Flash:
>
> - Canvas-based, rendered in IE using ExplorerCanvas that in turns relies on
>     VML
> - SVG on standard-based browsers, rendered as VML in IE
>
> There are pros and cons of both
>   approaches but for a charting library
>   I would recommend the later because it
>   is well integrated with DOM, allowing
>   to manipulate charts elements with the
>   DOM, and most importantly setting DOM
>   events. By contrast Canvas charting
>   libraries must reinvent the DOM wheel
>   to manage events. So unless you intend
>   to build static graphs with no event
>   handling, SVG/VML solutions should be
>   better.
>
> For SVG/VML solutions there are many
>   options, including:
>
> - Dojox Charting, good if you use the Dojo toolkit already
> - Raphael-based solutions
>
> Raphael is a very active, well
>   maintained, and mature, open-source
>   graphic library with very good
>   cross-browser support including IE 6
>   to 8, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome,
>   and Konqueror. Raphael does not depend
>   on any JavaScript framework and
>   therefore can be used with Prototype,
>   jQuery, Dojo, Mootools, etc...
>
> There are a number of charting
>   libraries based on Raphael, including
>   (but not limited to):
>
> - gRaphael, an extension of the Raphael    graphic library
> - Ico, with an intuitive API based on a    single function call to create
>     complex charts
>
> Disclosure: I am the developer of one
>   of the Ico forks on github
>   (http://github.com/uiteoi/ico).
>
> [by Jean Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library/2136455#2136455)

And other than this:

[Top 5 jQuery Chart Plug-ins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/)

If it is OK to use other than jQuery than [EJS Charts](http://www.ejschart.com/) are also very slick.