# What are some of the best performing JQuery Chart Plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking for multi browser support, and multi chart types (line,bar, etc). Besides chart support, main concern is performance on the browser, support/"active project", and extensibility.

Comment: Check out this answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery/1223619#1223619

Comment: @jimmy Not looking for piecharts, looking. Personally I think pie charts have no business in any UI.

Comment: :) That's why I pointed to an answer that didn't just mention pie charts.

Comment: Checkout Shield UI Charts: https://demos.shieldui.com/web/all-charts - most comprehensive, cross-browser and multi-device charting component.

Answer (score 6):

Highcharts - http://highcharts.com

Also, there are plugins for Highcharts in multiple development languages that generate the chart code for you, given sets of data..

Comment: Seconded - HighCharts is great.

Comment: License: Free for personal/Non-commercial use.

Comment: There also appears to be another free version on github from a pilot version. The charts are similar in design but the coding is completely different and you lose a ton of features. http://pmsipilot.github.com/jquery-highchartTable-plugin/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look [28 Rich Data Visualization Tools](http://1styearinfo.pbworks.com/f/28RichDataVisualizationTools.pdf), there are different chart and graph libraries, (also you can find jquery plugins). So you can compare them and pick the best for you.

[image]

Comment: The link redirects to some other page.

Comment: @Foreever, thanks! that article was written about 4 years ago, and migrated once, seems like now it is down again... I've managed to find it again :) link should be fixed for now, at least for some time :)

Answer (score 3):

Flot is a very popular choice. http://www.flotcharts.org/