# Build Jquery or CSS based chart from values of Divs on page

Tags: jquery, charts

Is it possible to build a Jquery or CSS chart based on the values in a set of Divs on a page?

i.e. on my page I have the following

```
Value One = <div id="q1">21</div>
Value Two = <div id="q2">40</div>
```

Then from that I want to build a bar chart with value one 21 and value two 40.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is that your question? What do you need help with?

Comment: I may not have asked the question correctly - the values are dynamic. that is they will be different every time the page is loaded - how do I call the DIV value in the Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't this question answer the same thing? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it possible, there's a great plugin called jqPlot that does just this.

http://www.jqplot.com/

Comment: Thanks Jake, I may not have asked the question correctly - the values are dynamic. that is they will be different every time the page is loaded - how do I call the DIV value in the Javascript?

Comment: If the page is being reloaded then the Javascript will rerun and update the chart automatically. To get the value from a div in jQuery, do `var one = $('#q1').html()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to do that:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 0):

You're better off giving them the same class, so you can loop through them as an array in jQuery:

```
<div class="bar" id="q1">21</div>
<div class="bar" id="q2">40</div>
```

Then:

`var bars = $('.bar')` - this gives you your collection

You need to determine which one is the biggest:

```
var maxBar = 0
for(var x=0;x<bars.length;x++) {
    if(parseInt($(bars[x]).text())>maxBar) {
       maxBar = parseInt($(bars[x]).text())
    }
}
```

From here, adjust the size of the bars in proportion to the largest:

```
for(var x=0;x<bars.length;x++) {
    mySize = parseInt($(bars[x]).text())
    $(bars[x]).css('width', parseInt(mySize/maxBar)*100)+'%')
}
```

Wrap your bars in a DIV and give it a width as desired.

Comment: OK that all makes sense to me, and thanks for that - however which plugin do I use for that? or do I use a plugin...sorry absolute noob here... :(

Comment: You don't need a plug-in, just jQuery.